# WaitForSingleObject() on a completion port?

Tags: winapi, io-completion-ports

Today I learned that I can call `CreateIoCompletionPort()` and then pass the returned `HANDLE` to `WaitForSingleObject()`:

```
#include <Windows.h>

int main()
{
    HANDLE h = CreateIoCompletionPort(INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE, nullptr, 0, 0);
    auto bRes = PostQueuedCompletionStatus(h, 1, 2, 0);
    if (!bRes) {
        abort();
    }

    auto dwRes = WaitForSingleObject(h, INFINITE);
    if (dwRes != WAIT_OBJECT_0){
        abort();
    }

    LPOVERLAPPED pOvr;
    DWORD cb;
    ULONG_PTR key;
    bRes = GetQueuedCompletionStatus(
        h, &cb, &key, &pOvr, INFINITE); // <-- returns 1, 2, nullptr

    if (!bRes) {
        abort();
    }

    dwRes = WaitForSingleObject(h, INFINITE); // <-- blocks here
    return 0;
}
```

It is working as expected on my Windows 10 box.

Is such behavior known or legal or documented? I was not able to find anything about it.

Comment: `dwRes = WaitForSingleObject(h, INFINITE); // <-- blocks here` - really block ? you sure ? just wondering

Comment: Yes. Crash dump in a wait state and source code here: https://1drv.ms/f/s!AtyOp6RRifUTuC2CAVzWdFrvZu6w

Comment: yes, in win10 really wait on KQUEUE dispatcher header. but say in win8.1 - no.

Comment: aha, Server 2016 TP5 doesn't wait as well, at least under kernel debugger -- second wait completes with WAIT_OBJECT_0.

Comment: i fast test - now in win10 (1607 build) IOCP work as NotificationEvent (manual reset even) - after PostQueuedCompletionStatus all threads, which wait on iocp is awaken but only one is remove packet

Answer (score 5):

If you read the [`WaitForSingleObject()` documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687032.aspx), an I/O Completion Port is **NOT** an allowed handle type:

> The `WaitForSingleObject` function can wait for the following objects:
>
> - Change notification
> - Console input
> - Event
> - Memory resource notification
> - Mutex
> - Process
> - Semaphore
> - Thread
> - Waitable timer

To wait for a completion event to arrive on the port, you must pass the handle to `GetQueuedCompletionStatus()` by itself and let it block until the event arrives or a timeout occurs.

```
#include <Windows.h>

int main()
{
    HANDLE h = CreateIoCompletionPort(INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE, nullptr, 0, 0);
    auto bRes = PostQueuedCompletionStatus(h, 1, 2, 0);
    if (!bRes) {
        abort();
    }

    LPOVERLAPPED pOvr;
    DWORD cb;
    ULONG_PTR key;
    bRes = GetQueuedCompletionStatus(
        h, &cb, &key, &pOvr, INFINITE); // <-- returns 1, 2, nullptr

    if (!bRes) {
        abort();
    }

    bRes = GetQueuedCompletionStatus(
        h, &cb, &key, &pOvr, INFINITE); // <-- blocks here

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for prompt response :-)

WaitForSingleObject() can as well wait on a file handle although it is not explicitly mentioned in the documentation for WaitForSingleObject() (see https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20121012-00/?p=6343, "a file handle is a waitable object").

I am fully aware about proper use of completion ports. I wonder whether a completion port is also a waitable object.

Comment: The documentation for [`GetOverlappedResult()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683209.aspx) mentions that a file, named pipe, and communications device handle are also waitable handles, but discourages waiting on them directly. But nothing in the [I/O Completion Ports documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365198.aspx) says an I/O completion port handle is directly waitable.  If something is not documented, don't rely on it.

Answer (score 2):

Summary:

- don't do it. See Remy Lebeau's answer and MSDN on how to use completion ports correctly.
- such abuse of completion ports is not only undocumented but also unreliable. Behavior varies between builds of Windows 10.
- completion port is probably a legit object for a wait in kernel since KQUEUE that backs a completion port has a DISPATCHER_HEADER.